# replace one div with another on hover

Tags: jquery, html, hover, dom-manipulation

I want to replace one div with another when hovering over it.  Specifically there will be an average in words, such as "struggling" or "exceeding expectations", and I want to replace this with the numerical average when the user hovers over the average in words.

```
#html

<div class="switch avg_words float_left">
  A+ (hover to see score)  
</div>
<div class="avg_num">
  AVG = 98.35%
</div>

#css

.avg_num {
display: none;
}

#jquery

$('.switch').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.avg_words').hide();
    $(this).next('div').closest('.avg_num').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).next('div').closest('.avg_num').hide();
    $(this).closest('.avg_words').show();
});
```

It's easy enough to hide the first div and replace it with the second, but the trouble is with the code to set things back to normal when hover ends.  Now on hover, the `div`s just blink back and forth between each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/uXeg2/1/

Comment: how can you do this with only CSS? Any good resource?

Comment: accepted answer is best and easiest way to do this, i think

Comment: I managed anyway: http://jsbin.com/nazase/3/edit?html,css,output. Any advice is welcome

Comment: wow that's a really beautiful solution, nicely done!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move the switch class to an outter div, like so

```
<div class="switch">
<div class="avg_words float_left">
  A+ (hover to see score)  
</div>
<div class="avg_num">
  AVG = 98.35%
</div>
</div>

$('.switch').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.avg_words').hide();
        $(this).find('.avg_num').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.avg_num').hide();
        $(this).find('.avg_words').show();
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXeg2/2/

Comment: find searches within the context of your selector, which you didn't have as both `div`s where on the same level. Nesting doesn't always make code pretty, but sure does help in cases like this.

Answer (score 4):

The blinking is a result of the way you set up your classes. Because `.switch` and `.avg_words` are the exact same element, this is what happens:

1. You hover `.switch`
2. `.avg_words` is hidden, which means `.switch` is hidden (it's the same div!)
3. Since `.switch` is hidden you are not hovering it anymore
4. `.avg_words` is shown immediately
5. You are now hovering `.switch` again because it was just shown (in step 4)
6. back to step 1

Instead, make sure `.switch` is an element wrapped around `.avg_words`, so that it does not get hidden once you hover it.

Comment: i thought that might be part of the problem - i was playing with that for awhile but couldn't get things to work because of the layers of divs. (couldn't figure out the right arrangement of `next` to use).  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This could be done in pure CSS as well, no need to rely on JQuery :

```
#html
<div class="switch">
<div class="avg_words float_left">
  A+ (hover to see score)
</div>
<div class="avg_num">
  AVG = 98.35%
</div>
</div>

#css
.avg_words {
  display:block
}

.avg_num {
  display:none
}

.switch:hover .avg_words {
  display:none
}

.switch:hover .avg_num {
  display:block
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your running into problems because you're hiding the same element that is bound to the hover event. Try changing your markup:

```
<div class="switch float_left">
    <div class="avg_words">
        A+ (hover to see score)  
    </div>
    <div class="avg_num">
      AVG = 98.35%
    </div>
</div>
```

Then change your javascript to something like this:

```
$('.switch').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.avg_words').hide();
        $(this).find('.avg_num').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.avg_num').hide();
        $(this).find('.avg_words').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `mouseover` and `mouseout` for that:

```
$('.switch .avg_words').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).closest('.avg_num').show();
});

$('.switch .avg_num').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).closest('.avg_words').show();
});
```

Comment: @agrothe not really, hover works for the same element, this alternative works on mouse-over for the first one, then on mouse-out for the second one ;)

Comment: true enough. I just try to avoid writing code like that myself, but it's just a personal preference I guess.